# Retrieve particular column value from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to retrieve the email address from my grid, so any one can help me to retrieve the email value alone from grid..
**CODE**

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email">
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

[image]

Comment: what you mean about retrieve did you mean from code behind ?

Comment: actually i need to pass the email value to send mail, so i need to save in a hidden field for sending mail..

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet please.

```
string[] emails="";

for (int i=0; i<Gridview.Rows.Count;i++)
{
   emails[i] = Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Your emails array contains all the e-mails of your Gridview rows.

If you want a specific email there is another approach, like this:

If the command of the linkbutton is UPDATE then the following will suffice:

```
protected void GridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   string email = GridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Comment: can you please say how to retrive specific email

Comment: Where do you choose from which row you will take the e-mail? Is there a button in the Gridview we don't see?

Comment: near to email i have a linkbutton called approve so if i click the linkbutton the customer status will get up-dated..sor for not displayng that linkbutton..

Comment: change the status from pending to approve in RowCommand of the grid

Comment: email value is not loaded it loads empty value

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in generic list

```
List<string> email = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i<Gridview.Rows.Count;i++)
{
  email.Add(Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
   }
```